# Apex Uploading PDF Failed to Load

Tags: apex, document, blob.topdf

There isn't any error after my Codes upload the File to the Document Folder.
But When I try to view the file that was uploaded I keep getting a **Fail To Load PDF Document** message.

Can Someone tell me whats the problem with my code?

---

### Apex Class

```
public class testFBInt {

public void exInt() {
 //converting to base64
String base64Data = '';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBodyAsBlob(Blob.valueOf('https://c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/Dashboard_PDF'));
req.setEndpoint('https://c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/Dashboard_PDF'); 
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
Blob PDF = res.getBodyAsBlob();
base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(PDF);
System.debug('@@ base64 @@' + base64Data );

//inserting into documents
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Name = 'SF_Dashboard.pdf';
doc.body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
doc.folderId = '00l6F000001pq8s'; //your folder id
doc.IsPublic = true;
doc.Description = 'Salesforce Dashboard Report -' + String.valueOf(date.today().format());

//insert doc;
insert doc;
System.debug('@@ doc @@' +doc);

//retrieving the file details
List<Document> lstfbdoc = [Select Id, Name, Description, Type FROM Document Where Name =: 'SF_Dashboard.pdf'];
 }
}
```

---

### VisualForce Page (Dashboard_PDF)

```
<apex:page name="Custom_Dash_Board" renderAs="PDF" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" title="Custom DashBoard">
<html>

<h2 >Sales</h2> 
<img src="https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=0FL6F000002dBX3&ruid=0056F00000746E0&did=01Z6F000001DwLb&s=7&fs=10&tfg=12&tfs=-16777063&explode=0&c=gauge&cs=0&title=Closed+Sales+To+Date&eh=no&compo=yes&fg=-16777216&bg1=-1&bg2=-3355393&bgdir=2&dl1=Account+Name&dl2=&l=2&sax=yes&Yman=no&nc=0&actUrl=%2F00O6F00000Aug7k%3Fdbw%3D1&sd=1&scv=no&sct=yes&spt=no&bd=yes&cu=SGD&ab=X&u=0&vt=0&ab2=Y&u2=1&vt2=2&vl0=Sum+of+Amount&spoc=no&topn=no&gm=0.0&gc0=-6750208&gm0=500000.0&gc1=-13210&gm1=1000000.0&gc2=-16738048&gm2=1500000.0&sona=0&refreshts=1491383581000" />

<h2 >Historical Snapshot</h2>
<img src="https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=0FL6F000002dBXF&ruid=0056F00000746E0&did=01Z6F000001DwLb&s=6&fs=10&tfg=12&tfs=-16777063&explode=0&c=column&cs=2&title=&eh=no&compo=yes&fg=-16777216&bg1=-1&bg2=-3355393&bgdir=2&dl1=As+of+Date&dl2=Historical+Stage&l=2&sax=yes&Yman=no&nc=0&actUrl=%2F00O6F00000Aug7w%3Fdbw%3D1&sd=1&scv=no&sct=no&spt=no&bd=yes&cu=SGD&ab=X&u=0&vt=0&ab2=Y&u2=0&vt2=2&vl0=Sum+of+Historical+Amount&spoc=no&topn=no&gc0=-4041644&gc1=-4013484&gc2=-11222444&sona=0&refreshts=1491458466000" />

</html>
</apex:page>
```

---

### Message When Trying to View the PDF

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to save your visualforce('Dashboard_PDF') as a Document?

Comment: yes i'm trying to save the Visualforce (Dashboard_PDF) as a document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a litle change in your code.

Can you try this ?

```
PageReference pagePDF = Page.Dashboard_PDF;
Blob bodyPage = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('Test') : pagePDF.getContentAsPDF();

Document doc = new Document();
doc.Name = 'SF_Dashboard.pdf';
doc.body = bodyPage;
doc.folderId = '00l6F000001pq8s'; //your folder id
doc.IsPublic = true;
doc.Description = 'Salesforce Dashboard Report -' + String.valueOf(date.today().format());

//insert doc;
insert doc;
```